# AWS Honeycode: #value! error using sum() over a filtered column

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax-error, amazon-honeycode

I am developing an app in aws honeycode where I am using a filter in one column and I want to use that column for sum in another column but it showing me error as #value

Answer (score 0):

Better to show what you have tried, but here is the required argument for the sum function.

```
=SUM(Filter(Tasks, "Tasks[Milestone]=%", "Work")[Points])
```

> Filter output or columns can be used as an argument in functions like SUM, COUNT, COUNTA.

[image]

[honeycode filter](https://honeycodecommunity.aws/t/filter/923)